# OpenUI5: Access model in component

Tags: model, components, sapui5

I have a component that represents a web application:

```
sap.ui.define( ["sap/ui/core/UIComponent"], function (UIComponent) {
"use strict";
return UIComponent.extend("dividendgrowthtools.Component", {

    metadata: ...
    init : function () {

        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        ...

        // set i18n model
        ...
        var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
                            bundleUrl: [rootPath, mConfig.resourceBundle].join("/"),
                            bundleLocale: sCurrentLocale });

        this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");

        // redirect the "dividendgrowthtools" package to the local web app
        jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("dividendgrowthtools", "/");

        }

});
}, /* bExport= */ true);
```

In that component I set the i18n model.

Furthermore I have a helper object which I want to use to switch the language of the app:

```
jQuery.sap.require("jquery.sap.resources");

jQuery.sap.declare("dividendgrowthtools.util.Helper");

Helper = {
    ...

    switchLanguage: function(sLocale) {

    // set new locale
    sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage(sLocale);

    // load and set new ressource bundle
    var rootPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("dividendgrowthtools");

    var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
                            bundleUrl: [rootPath, "i18n/messageBundle.properties"].join("/"),
                            bundleLocale: sLocale
        });

    // does not work as it's not the component model (set to core)
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");

...
```

The idea was to load and set a new i18n model. The problem is, that I could not find a possibility to access the component respectively the i18n model which I set in the init method of the component.

Does anybody know how to request a component reference or how to access the model set in the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to pass the controller object from the calling controller. You would change your Helper function to sth. like this:

```
switchLanguage(sLocale, oController): function() {
   var oComponent = oController.getOwnerComponent();
   ...
}
```

You would then call the method from your controller function as follows:

```
callMyHelperFunction: function() {
   Helper.switchLanguage("en", this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found is the following:

1. Create the component like this (to ensure that the component gets a nice id):

   ```
           // create component
           var oMainComponent = sap.ui.getCore().createComponent({
                name: "dividendgrowthtools",
                id: "maincomponent"
           });

           // create and place component container
           var oComponentContainer = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer("componentcontainer", {
                    component: oMainComponent
           });
           oComponentContainer.placeAt("content");
   ```
2. Get the component reference via it's id in the Helper object and set new model:

   ```
   var oComponent = sap.ui.getCore().getComponent("maincomponent"); 
   oComponent.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
   ```

Comment: Note, that this will not work if your component is reused or used in for example the Fiori Launchpad.

Comment: Could you please explain why it would not work (it's not used in that ways - however - I would like to understand why not)? Is it because I access the UI core in the helper object?

Comment: Because in your component you are relying on the way the component got created. There might be environments where you cannot control the id given to your component.

Comment: Ah - that's true! Thanks for the clarification!